# Can't execute Switch statement inside For Loop more than 10 times - C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

i'm currently learning C, and i have an exercise, request for 20 characters and show the amount of ('a','e','i','o','u').
I coded this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, x;
    for(x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a character: ");
        letter = getchar();
        letter = tolower(letter);
        switch(letter)
        {
            case 'a':
                a += 1;
                break;
            case 'e':
                e += 1;
                break;
            case 'i':
                i += 1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                o += 1;
                break;
            case 'u':
                u += 1;
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    printf("\nAmount of 'a': %d", a);
    printf("\nAmount of 'e': %d", e);
    printf("\nAmount of 'i': %d", i);
    printf("\nAmount of 'o': %d", o);
    printf("\nAmount of 'u': %d\n", u);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But this only can be executed 10 times. Why this happens?
PD. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Your program runs fine [demo](http://ideone.com/XOiq9X).

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ after the first input, it shows: "Enter a character:" (newline) "Enter a character: _"

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your version works because the ideone stdin is not line buffered, and you do not enter `\n` in it. When running from a terminal, the stdlin line buffering will force the user to press enter between each letter, thus adding a second character: the '\n' (like @user3121023 said).

Comment: @NiBZ It's not "my version", it's a copy-paste of OP's code, with `system("cls")` and `system("pause")` removed. I understand why it runs differently on ideone than on OP's computer. My comment was intended as a hint to OP that his code is fine, and he should look for the problem elsewhere.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which is likely to be used by your IDE). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) e.g. to run the program step by step. Also, put `\n` at end of `printf` format strings (because of line buffering)

Comment: @user3121023 it works! thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i understood your point, adding that "x" inside showed me where my mistake was, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are processing 20 characters, but half of them are newlines.  If you take out your line `system("cls")` this becomes apparent:

```
% ./ctest

Enter a character: a

Enter a character: 
Enter a character: b

Enter a character: 
Enter a character: c
```

At the first prompt, I typed `a<RET>` and the first loop iteration (`x=0`) processed the `a` but there is still a `<RET>` waiting in the input buffer.  The second loop iteration (`x=1`) gets the next available character, `<RET>` and processes it, the the third loop iteration (`x=2`) prints its prompt and waits for new input.

You can further see how this works by getting it to process 20 characters you are counting.  For example, if I provide the input `aaaaaeeeeeiiiiiooooo<RET>`, which is 21 characters, you can see that the first 20 are processed:

```
 % ./ctest

Enter a character: aaaaaeeeeeiiiiiooooo

Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Enter a character: 
Amount of 'a': 5
Amount of 'e': 5
Amount of 'i': 5
Amount of 'o': 5
Amount of 'u': 0
```

To fix this problem you should either read and discard the newline character or use a different method of reading that can ignore the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore newline chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()

{
    char letter;
    int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0, x;
    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a character: ");
        letter = getchar();
        letter = tolower(letter);
        if (letter == '\n')
        {
            x--;
            system("cls");
            continue;
        }
        if (letter)
        {
            switch (letter)
            {
            case 'a':
                a += 1;
                break;
            case 'e':
                e += 1;
                break;
            case 'i':
                i += 1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                o += 1;
                break;
            case 'u':
                u += 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        system("cls");
    }
    printf("\nAmount of 'a': %d", a);
    printf("\nAmount of 'e': %d", e);
    printf("\nAmount of 'i': %d", i);
    printf("\nAmount of 'o': %d", o);
    printf("\nAmount of 'u': %d\n", u);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You can use scanf instead of getchar, it will also solve it.

Comment: i've tried using scanf but it didn't works, really need to modify the code. ty!